# What is this form: Vb + あう + Noun

Tags: grammar, compound-verbs

As I was browsing the Nintendo e-shop, I noticed a [new title](http://social.gust.co.jp/shiroyuri/) whose tagline is:

> 美少女｛びしょうじょ｝と美少女と美少女が惹｛ひ｝かれあうRPG

(Don't judge...)

How to interpret this 惹かれるあう? I understand that the appeal of the RPG are the (numerous) beautiful girls, but what nuance does it bring?

My dictionary only gives 会う/合う as possible writings for あう but I am not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: Hint: The 「れ」 is the key syllable.  In what verb forms would 「れ」 be found?

Comment: I judged. Sorry.

Comment: @l'électeur : It was late, I now realize my mistake...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A verb + しあう means "to do together(each other), so 惹かれあう means "to be attracted to each other".

美少女と美少女と美少女が惹かれあう modifies a noun "RPG".